# Julia: How to set the number of DataFrame rows printed in IJulia/Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ijulia-notebook

```
using DataFrames
DataFrame(a = 1:100)
```

Prints about 30 rows in IJulia/Jupyter by default.

How can I set the number of rows to print in IJulia/Jupyter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display `n` rows simply set

```
Base.displaysize() = (n, 80)
```